# subscribe to wp through a Faceboo app

Tags: facebook

Has anyone heard of a way to get allow people to subscribe to a wp blog, while in Facebook, such as through a Facebook app? Basically, I am looking for a widget or similarly functioning feature that I can embed into a page of a Facebook application that has an subscribe form for a particular wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apps are just an iFrame back to a page you host somewhere.

So you could build out a page in your WordPress site with your subscription options. For example, using JetPack http://jetpack.me/support/subscriptions/. And then embed that page into a Facebook app and add it as a tab to your Facebook page.

:)

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking of......and iFrame like that as an FB tab, but I've never used  JetPack, so I didn't know it had a subscription widget in it.